# Arch Linux gdb immediately crashes

Tags: linux, gdb, archlinux, guile

I recently installed gdb on my archlinux system and anytime I use gdb it immediately crashes with the message:

> Throw without catch before boot:
>
> Throw to key
>
> Error while printing exception:
>
> Key:
>
> Failed to print exception.
>
> Aborting.

When I say "use it", I mean anything. Entering "gdb" by itself causes this, entering "gdb -help" causes it, entering the gdb command at all results in this error. Any ideas what I should look at to correct it?

Comment: Looks like it's trying to use `guile`. You probably need to install `guile` and/or `guile-devel`, too.

Comment: Guile is already installed, but it does appear to be the problem. running guile -h produces the same message as above.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem that was caused by glibc-locale not being installed.  You might give this a shot.